# How to use @if within @function to check the orientation of the screen in SCSS?

Tags: sass

I've been trying to write conditional SCSS that sets the height of my device to one value if the device is landscape or another if it is in portrait.

I understand I can use a media query to determine the orientation but I don't believe I'm receiving the correct calculation. Currently this is what I have. How can I check that my condition is written properly?

```
@function calculateRootHeight ($width, $orientation: landscape)
{
  $heightPaddedRatio: 1.0;
  $heightToWidth: 2/3;
  @if (orientation: portrait) {
    $heightToWidth: 3/2;
  }
  @return $heightPaddedRatio * $heightToWidth * $width;
}

@mixin describeRoot($bodyWidth) {
  #root {
    background-color: #EAE5E5;
  }
  @media (orientation: portrait) {
    #root {
      height: calculateRootHeight($bodyWidth, portrait);
    }
  }
  @media (orientation: landscape) {
    #root {
      height: calculateRootHeight($bodyWidth, landscape);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to change the syntax in your `@if` statement slightly, the rest seems ok.

Using the `@debug` directive is helpful if you want to check a value in your Sass functions.

```
@function calculateRootHeight ($width, $orientation: landscape) {
  $heightPaddedRatio: 1.0;
  $heightToWidth: 2/3;

  @if ($orientation == "portrait") {
    $heightToWidth: 3/2;
  }  

  @debug "Orientation is '#{$orientation}'";
  @return $heightPaddedRatio * $heightToWidth * $width;
}

.portrait {
  height: calculateRootHeight(200px, portrait); /* Orientation is 'portrait' */
}

.landscape {
  height: calculateRootHeight(200px); /* Orientation is 'landscape' */
}
```

Comment: Right now I'm developping in React on Webstorm using a File Watcher to automatically preprocess the SCSS. Where can I display the debugged output? Can I display it in the browser in any way?

Comment: I never tried Webstorm, but as far as I can tell the keyboard shortcut `Alt+F12` will show the console. Hopefully you will see the Sass debug output there.